# Magento2: Too many simple products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, backend

We recently moved from magento1 to magento2. The price and product structure seems to be different in magento2.

*Example:* We sell bags in 20 different colors and with 5 different (selectable) accessories so after generating configuration we get 100 simple products for each bag!

In magento1 we only had 20 simple products (priced at 0$) for each color that were assigned to each configurable product. The price was defined by the configurable product and the accessories would add x$ to the price.

I am not sure if I did something wrong.. Is it normal to have so many products in magento2 and is there a reason to this ?

Comment: I guess that you did some customization on magento1. that  why it is showing  20Simple product, As per as, magento logic ,it should show 100 product (20*5) at magento 1 also